# what are the advantages of spring aop over filters,both look similar in applications

Tags: java, spring, filter

My doubt is , both aspected oriented prpgramming and filters are used for same purposes esp around aspect oriented programming method... which is better to use

Comment: In what context? Do you mean servlet filters?

Answer (score 12):

Servlet Filters are limited for manipulating the http request/ response.

With AOP you can intercept and manipuate each method invokation on every Spring Bean.

Comment: tx, fr ur answer. wen  der s possibility of using both which is preferred?? Does servlet filters makes program slow compared to AOP??

Comment: I feel that well written Servlet Filters should be preferred over AOP (where possible), because it is more standardized. And Servlet Filters are not slower (of course it depends on what you do, but just the invocation of a servlet filter is a normal method invocation).